# Filtering out HTML elements which have 'display:none' either as a tag attribute or in their CSS

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Let's say you have some html source that's been scraped with Selenium, and parsed with BeautifulSoup:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

Is there a way to remove, from the html code or the soup object, all elements which either have:

1.) the attribute `style=display:none` within the html tag source (i.e. `<div style = 'display:none'>...</div>`)

or

2.) have the `display:none` property within the page's CSS

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your end goal - might make easier for us to help? Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe - Thanks, alecxe - I'm trying to scrape the IP addresses from the proxy list [here](http://proxylist.hidemyass.com). The page seems to obscure the HTML code for the IP addresses by placing `display:none` elements around the elements containing the information of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I remember dealing with a web-site like this - the IP address was internally represented via multiple HTML elements, some of them were hidden  via `display: none` style, some had an appropriate CSS class that made them invisible. Getting the real IP address out of this mess via `BeautifulSoup` was quite difficult.

Good news is that [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) actually handles this use case and whenever you get the `.text` of a `WebElement` - it would return you a *visible text of an element* which is exactly what is needed.

Demo:

```
In [1]: from selenium import webdriver

In [2]: driver = webdriver.Firefox()

In [3]: driver.get("http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/")

In [4]: for row in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("section.proxy-results table#listable tr")[1:]: 
   ...:     cells = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
   ...:     print(cells[1].text.strip())
   ...: 
101.26.38.162
120.198.236.10
213.85.92.10
...
216.161.239.51
212.200.111.198
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you! I guess I should explore Selenium's parsing features a bit more, rather than sticking with BeautifulSoup, to which I've gotten accustomed.