# How to remove elements with style display:none from HTML source code

Tags: html, css, web-scraping

I was reading a 4-year-old [blog article](https://blueshellgroup.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/creating-a-private-database-of-proxies-part-2/) about how to scrape IP addresses and port numbers from http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/. Although the article is unfinished and doesn't include any code, it seems like the obfuscation techinque they describe is still the one being used by HideMyAss.

For example, here is a `<span>` element corresponding to an IP address:

```
<span>
  <style>
    .p6ox{ display:none }
    .arbS{ display:inline }
    .fjtd{ display:none }
    .X9U3{ display:inline }
  </style>
  <span class="31">171</span>
  <span class="X9U3">.</span>
  38
  <span style="display:none">196</span>
  <div style="display:none">196</div>
  <span style="display: inline">.</span>
  <span class="96">66</span>
  <span class="fjtd">223</span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="X9U3">.</span>
  <span style="display: inline">144</span>
</span>
```

here is how it is (more legibly) rendered by Chrome's 'Inspect Element',

[image]

and here is the IP address as rendered:

[image]

It seems like HideMyAss is making it more difficult to read the IP address by including 'decoy' `<span>` sub-elements with `display:none`, which is either achieved directly through the `style` attribute or indirectly through assigning a `class` whose `{display:none}`.

In order to remove this obfuscation, I'm looking for a tool which essentially takes in HTML and 'renders' in a way that it simply removes elements with `display:none`. Do any such tools already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ( $(element).css('display') == 'none' ){
    $(element).remove();
}
```

If you are using javascript to modify the html they give, you can loop through each element and check its css.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
const el = document.getElementById('element-to-remove');
const display = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('display');
if ( display === 'none' ) el.remove();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Filtering out HTML elements which have 'display:none' either as a tag attribute or in their CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597616/filtering-out-html-elements-which-have-displaynone-either-as-a-tag-attribute), this can also be achieved in a facile manner using the [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).